# Adding new xml element and changing the value of an element within the same parent element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to make certain modifications to my XML input, depending on certain conditions. I am using XSLT 1.0.

1. the value of the `message_type` element (child element of `m_cotrol`) should be changed
2. A new element `message_status` should be added (as a child of the `m_control` element).

These changes are reflected in the expected output XML. With my current XSLT code, I am only able to achieve the second requirement.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-04-12T09:24:38.902</control_timestamp>
    <message_id>a50ec030-72ab</message_id>
    <retry_number>0</retry_number>
    <message_type>Request</message_type>
    <message_version>test.XSD</message_version>
    <expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
    <initiator_id>FST</initiator_id>
    <initiator_orchestration_id>1637280</initiator_orchestration_id>
    <responder_id>mycomp</responder_id>
  </m_control>
  <m_content>
    <b_control>
      <service_provider_reference_number>650971</service_provider_reference_number>
      <intermediary_case_reference_number>Sample1</intermediary_case_reference_number>
      <quote_type>Comparison</quote_type>
      <quote_or_print>Print</quote_or_print>
      <message_version_number>3.7</message_version_number>
      <submission_date>0001-04-12</submission_date>
    </b_control>
  </m_content>
</message>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<message xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <m_control>
    <control_timestamp>2013-04-12T09:24:38.902</control_timestamp>
    <message_id>a50ec030-72ab</message_id>
    <retry_number>0</retry_number>
    <message_type>Response</message_type>
    <message_version>test.XSD</message_version>
    <expected_response_type>synchronous</expected_response_type>
    <initiator_id>FST</initiator_id>
    <initiator_orchestration_id>1637280</initiator_orchestration_id>
    <responder_id>mycomp</responder_id>
    <message_status>User not allowed access</message_status>
  </m_control>
  <m_content>
    <b_control>
      <service_provider_reference_number>650971</service_provider_reference_number>
      <intermediary_case_reference_number>Sample1</intermediary_case_reference_number>
      <quote_type>Comparison</quote_type>
      <quote_or_print>Print</quote_or_print>
      <message_version_number>3.7</message_version_number>
      <submission_date>0001-04-12</submission_date>
      <quote_response_status>Error</quote_response_status>
      <quote_error_note>
        <reason>[Error] Check if the User has access to the requested service</reason>
      </quote_error_note>
    </b_control>
  </m_content>
</message>
```

**XSLT code:**  Based on the value of DataPower variable (var://service/error-message), I need the expected output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'m_control')]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="dp:variable('var://service/error-message') = 'not present'">
      <m_control xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
        <message_status>User not recognized</message_status>
      </m_control>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'b_control')]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="dp:variable('var://service/error-subcode')='0x01d30002'">
      <b_control xmlns="http://www.origoservices.com">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
        <quote_response_status>Error</quote_response_status>
        <quote_error_note>
          <reason>[Error] Check if the User has access to the requested service</reason>
        </quote_error_note>
      </b_control>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please add your XSLT stylesheet to the post - to prove that you already made an effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: I have added the XSLT in the question.

Comment: Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Say _exactly_ what is wrong with your XLST code and what the changes should be.

Comment: Appologies, I have edited my question. Here's is my requirement: If you see in expected output.I need two kinds of transformations based upon certial conditions. i) value of message_type element ( Child element of 'm_cotrol') will be changed ii) A new element message_status is to be added (Under m_control element). As shown in expected output xml. But with the xslt that I am trying , I am able to achieve only 2nd requirement and not the both

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet meets both of your requirements. It does a common identity transform (which your XSLT does, too) with exceptions.

Note that I have not taken into consideration any changes that are performed by your stylesheet but not listed as a requirement (i.e. changing `quote_error_note` and `quote_response_status`).

This line:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[parent::ori:message_type]">
```

meets your first requirement, the one you were unable to code. It matches the text content of `message_type` and outputs "Response" instead.

But this solution differs from yours in another way: it does *not* match elements along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'m_control')]">
```

Rather, their correct namespace is identified:

```
<xsl:template match="ori:m_control">
```

Now, what's the difference? Your way of describing the template match allows elements of *any* namespace to be matched. This might not be a problem in your case (no conflicting namespaces) but it could be one in general.

**Full stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ori="http://www.origoservices.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
exclude-result-prefixes="ori xsi">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ori:m_control">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <message_status>
        <xsl:text>User not allowed access</xsl:text>
     </message_status>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="text()[parent::ori:message_type]">
  <xsl:text>Response</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```